# Templated Q_OBJECT base class

Tags: c++, qt, oop, inheritance, qobject

I have a couple of classes:

```
A.h
class Abase_obj : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QAction* playAction READ playAction CONSTANT)
public:
    Abase_obj(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}
    virtual QAction* playAction() = 0;

signals:
    void someSignal()
slots:
    virtual void baseSlot() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Abase : public Abase_obj
{
public:
    Abase(QObject* parent = nullptr) : Abase_obj(parent) {...}
    void baseSlot() override;
    QAction* playAction() override;
protected:
    QWeakPointer<T> m_currentItem;
};

template <class T>
Abase<T>::baseSlot() {
   auto item = m_currentItem.lock();
   item->someMethodOfTemplateClass(); // here is the error
}
```

B_inh.h

```
#include "A.h"

class MediaItem;
class B_inh : public Abase<MediaItem>
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(MediaItem* getItem READ getItem)
public:
    // constructor
    MediaItem* getItem();
public slot:
    // some new slot

}
```

So I use Abase_obj as I can't type Q_OBJECT macro in the templated class and define there some slots and signals. I know that I can define there slots which doesn't has templated *parametres*. But I am using the template method directly in this slot. But as Abase_obj metaobject doesn't know about this class, I get the error: *error: C2039: 'someMethodOfTemplateClass': is not a member of 'QSharedPointer'* and *error: C2027: use of undefined type 'MediaItem'*. So I have 2 questions: first one is how should I implement this slot so it could work, and the second question is in the comment above.

Upd: If I make *#include "MediaItem.h"* instead of forward declaring it, I am getting errors:

```
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const Abase_obj::staticMetaObject" : in file B_inh.cpp.obj
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl Abase_obj::qt_metacast(char const *)" : in file B_inh.cpp.obj
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl Abase_obj::metaObject(void)const " : in file B_inh.cpp.obj
```

If I remove Q_OBJECT macro and all Q_PROPERTies from Abase_obj and add them to the B_inh class, everything is compiling and working, but I don't want to implement these properties every time in all of the derived classes

Comment: What if you include header where `MediaItem` is declared instead of forward declaring it?

Comment: I am getting some linker errors:
```
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const Abase_obj::staticMetaObject"
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl Abase_obj::qt_metacast(char const *)"

LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl Abase_obj::metaObject(void)const "
```

Comment: Looks like the moc file is not compiled in. Make sure moc is running and generates moc_A.h

Comment: @chehrlic how can I check it?

Comment: I tried building your code. I had to fix some typos, and fill in empty implementations of functions, and make up a definition of MediaItem. But it worked fine. I'm not getting any errors. So I think the problem is elsewhere. Does your build process include `moc`? I used a qmake project that handles that automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct. The mistake was in my **qbs dependencies**. File A.h just haven't been compiled and haven't been correctly included to the B_inh.h, so I had these linker errors